# Sidebar tooltip not showing on anchor hover

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to implement a tooltip feature when a user hovers over a sidebar navigation item. It is currently being rendered in the DOM but I can not get it to display no matter what I change in the styles. I have attempted adding a `z-index`, changing the display and position attributes but to no success. Any CSS experts out there know what would be causing this? Link to the codepen [here](https://codepen.io/teecp/pen/gOYRwbO).

**HTML:**

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b61e574d7a.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Home</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Crown</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">History</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Send</span>
  </a>
  <div class="sidebar-bottom">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
      <span class="tooltip">Send feedback</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle preferences"></i>
      <span class="tooltip">Preferences</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  hello
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #7b68ee;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;

  a {
    position: relative;
    left: 17.5%;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    border-radius: 90px;
    width: 20%;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;

    &:hover {
      background: #ffffff1a;
      transition: 0.3s;
    }

    .fa, .far, .fas {
      line-height: 50px;
    }

    .tooltip {
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: black;
      padding: 8px 15px;
      border-radius: 3px;
      margin-top: -26px;
      left: 90px;
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      font-size: 13px;
      letter-spacing: .5px;

      &:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: -4px;
        top: 10px;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background-color: inherit;
      }
    }

    &:hover {
      background-color: green;

      .tooltip {
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }

    &.active {
      background-color: pink;

      i {
        color: purple;
      }
    }   
  }

  .sidebar-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made adjustments to your code in order to make it work. On `:hover`, the `span` which has a default `display: none`, will be displayed via `display: block`. You were referring to the anchor direclty, but you should consider the `span` that's inside the anchor (`a`) element.

```css
.tooltip {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

a:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

See this snippet for the solution to your problem.

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #7b68ee;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar a {
  position: relative;
  left: 17.5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 20%;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

main .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

.sidebar-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 4rem;
}

.fa,
.far,
.fas {
  line-height: 50px !important;
}

.tooltip {
  font-size: 10px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  display: none;
  padding: 2px 4px;
}

a:hover .tooltip {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b61e574d7a.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Home</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Crown</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">History</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Send</span>
  </a>
  <div class="sidebar-bottom">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
      <span class="tooltip">Send feedback</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle preferences"></i>
      <span class="tooltip">Preferences</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove 
`overflow-x:hidden` from .sidebar class and make some changes in `.sidebar a .tooltip { top:10px; left:70px;}` and add some style for `#main { padding-left:75px; width:100%;}`

**CSS**

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}
 .sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #7b68ee;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
 .sidebar a {
  position: relative;
  left: 17.5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 20%;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
 .sidebar a:hover {
  background: #fff 1a;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
 .sidebar a .fa, .sidebar a .far, .sidebar a .fas {
  line-height: 50px;
}
 .sidebar a .tooltip {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
 .sidebar a .tooltip:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -4px;
  top: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: inherit;
}
 .sidebar a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
 .sidebar a:hover .tooltip {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
 .sidebar a.active {
  background-color: pink;
}
 .sidebar a.active i {
  color: purple;
}
 .sidebar .sidebar-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
 #main {
     padding-left: 75px;
     width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b61e574d7a.js"></script>

<div class="sidebar">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Home</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Crown</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-history"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">History</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
    <span class="tooltip">Send</span>
  </a>
  <div class="sidebar-bottom">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-comment-dots"></i>
      <span class="tooltip">Send feedback</span>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fas fa-user-circle preferences"></i>
      <span class="tooltip">Preferences</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
  hello
</div>
```